# Need to create different sections in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview

I have 2 arrays that contain people's first names like John or Steve. The first array contains people that are in my server's database and already use my app. The second array contains people that were in the user's address book, but are not in my database and have never used my app before.

Right now when I display these names on my UITableView, they are all together and there is no separation.

I need to create 2 different sections in my UITableView, one section for each array. The first array's section will be called "Users from your address book that use this app", and then the 2nd array's section would be called "These people don't use the app yet."

I am basically trying to achieve exactly what this image shows: http://appdupe.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/snapchat-clone-script-add.png

Notice how there is a section called "Friends On Snapchat" and then a 2nd section called "Invite Friends From Contacts".

How can I create these same "sections" for my UITableView?

Here are the current method implemenations that I use to setup my table view:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.potentiaFriendsFirstNamesArray count];
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"SettingsCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];


    NSString *firstNameForTableView = [self.potentiaFriendsFirstNamesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *userNameForTableView = [self.potentiaFriendsUsernameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    [cell.textLabel setText:firstNameForTableView];
    [cell.detailTextLabel setText:userNameForTableView];
    return cell;
}

-(NSString*)stringBetweenString:(NSString*)start andString:(NSString *)end withstring:(NSString*)str
{
    NSScanner* scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:str];
    [scanner setCharactersToBeSkipped:nil];
    [scanner scanUpToString:start intoString:NULL];
    if ([scanner scanString:start intoString:NULL]) {
        NSString* result = nil;
        if ([scanner scanUpToString:end intoString:&result]) {
            return result;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Access is denied on your image example.

Comment: Works just fine for me. Try here: http://i58.tinypic.com/rkt0qr.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement the numberOfSectionsInTableView and sectionIndexTitlesForTableView methods of UITableViewDataSource protocol and also alter your current numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAtIndexPath. Something like this:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 2;
}

- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Users from your address book that use this app", @"These people don't use the app yet", nil];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section == 0) {
        return [self.firstArrayOfUsers count];
    } else {
        return [self.secondArrayOfUsers count];
    }
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"SettingsCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    NSString* userName = nil;

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        username = [self.firstArrayOfUsers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else {
        username = [self.secondArrayOfUsers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    [cell.textLabel setText:username];
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To create two sections you need to implement `– numberOfSectionsInTableView:`. It is a UITableViewDataSource Protocol method. Then you can distinguish two sections in `– tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` using `if (indexPath.section == 0) {...} else if (indexPath.section == 1) {...}`. After this you can implement `- tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:` to give a title to each section.

Note that your tableView has to be of style `UITableViewStyleGrouped`. Table view has property style of type UITableViewStyle:

```
typedef enum {
   UITableViewStylePlain,
   UITableViewStyleGrouped
} UITableViewStyle;
```